# GetValue(...) - Error is ignored in Runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

Trying to create Enum extension method that gets any enum attribute value, I bumped in the following situation:

When compiling the code below VS 2010 shows an error of : No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 argument.
When commenting the code and using the watch tool - the line returns the value (see attached image).

Any idea why?

```
 public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<object> GetAttributeValue(this Enum enm, Type attribute, string attributeName)
    {

        FieldInfo fi = enm.GetType().GetField(enm.ToString());

        var fiAtts = fi.GetCustomAttributes(attribute, false);

        if (fiAtts.Length == 0)
            return null;


        foreach (var att in fiAtts)
        {
            //VS2010 throws an error: No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 argument
            //yield ==> Ignore
            return att.GetType().GetProperty(attributeName).GetValue(att);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, there is no `GetValue` method that only takes one argument as parameter in .Net 4 for the [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) class

The only possibility I can see right now for the watch window to return something, is that somewhere in your code your have a `GetValue` extension method for the `PropertyInfo` type that only needs one parameter as input. It could be unknown in your code because no `using [PropertyInfoExtensionNamespace]` is specified. Maybe for an unknown (or buggy) reason, it's known for the debugger.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2010/07/22/extension-methods-and-the-debugger.aspx) for a discussion about extension methods + debugger buggy behaviors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I managed reproduce the mentioned behavior without using extension methods, and there is no extension method GetValue which takes a single argument as mentioned - I will keep investigating and inform this thread.